# Shapeless - Generic in a Generic context

Tags: scala, shapeless

This is a subquestion from a post I made earlier today.

I am working with HList and Generic hoping to perform some implicit conversion between case classes.

Consider:

```
case class A(a: Int, b: Double, c: Boolean)
case class B(b: Double, c: Boolean)
```

I can convert between the two types very simply:

```
Generic[B].from(Generic[A].to(A(1, 2.0, true)).tail) // B(2.0, true)
```

I want to be able to pimp a method onto Product so I can do the following:

```
A(1, 2.0, true).to[B]
```

My attempt is as follows:

```
object ShapelessTest extends App {

  implicit class convert[From <: Product, FromHListT <: HList]
    (x: From)(implicit genFrom: Generic.Aux[From, FromHlistT]){

    def to[To <: Product, ToHlistT <: HList]
      (implicit genTo: Generic.Aux[To, ToHilstT]): To = {

      val fromHList = genFrom.to(x)

      val toHList = ??? // Manipulate toHList to correspond with type ToHListT

      genTo.from(toHList)
    }
  }

  println(C(1, 2.0, true).to[D, Double :: Boolean :: HNil])
}
```

Now my code is less than ideal for two reasons.

1. I have to explicitly supply the Type of the To HList.
2. I need to manipulate the FromHListT instance (perhaps selecting values by index) and then ensure it is of Type ToHListT.

Does anyone have any advice how I can obtain Generic.Aux[T, ToHListT] without having to specify a second type parameter?

2. Can anyone advise how I can manipulate (remove items from, reorder FromHListT) and convert to instance of ToHListT.

Comment: Do you always want to remove just the first element as in the example? If yes, you can use `IsHCons.Aux` to prove tail of `FromHListT` is of type `ToHListT `. See https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L44

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Comment: For example from a :: b :: c :: d :: HNil I may need  b :: d :: a :: HNil. I can determine the indices of the elements I need from additional implicit parameter (omitted for clarity). I guess I would like the ability to do something like fromHList(1) :: fromHList(2) :: HNil. I understand that this would not solve my FromHListT/ToHListT type inconsistency

Comment: If you want to select by indices, `fromHList.selectMany(1, 2)` should do the trick. In shapeless tests there is also an example how to select by types https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/cb973aa10f066782e8543fdce8d44b2d83996801/core/src/test/scala/shapeless/hlist.scala#L3075

Answer (score 0):

You should read chapter "6.3 Case study: case class migrations" of "The Type Astronaut’s Guide to Shapeless"
https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html#sec:ops:migration

Basically when you would like to hide extra generics you introduce a type class.

Also instead of implicit `g: Generic.Aux[A, B]` you can try to use implicit `g: Generic[A]` and type `g.Repr` instead of `B`.

Comment: I did try using the T : Generic notation but got confused when Generic[T].to did not return an HList

Comment: I understand that Generic[T]#Repr is a type that represents the second parameter of Generic.Aux. I don't understand how I can convert that to an HList and perform operations such as .selectMany etc.